# Using 1D convolutional with same shape so it will work with FFT?

Tags: matlab, vector, fft, convolution

I'm trying to make `conv(x, k, 'same')` result the same as `FFT`. But I notice that this only works for the shape `full` and not for `same`.

```
% Create vector and kernel
x = randn(1, 100); 
k = randn(1, 10);  

% Do 1D conv
y_conv = conv(x, k, 'full');

% Do 1D FFT
N = length(x) + length(k) - 1;
X = fft(x, N);
K = fft(k, N);
Y_fft = ifft(X .* K);

% Compare
max_diff = max(abs(y_conv - Y_fft));
disp(['The maximal difference is: ' num2str(max_diff)]);
```

The reason why I want to have `same`, is because my output data need to be the same as input data.

**Question:**

What need to be done/changed, for make FFT result the same as `conv(x, k, 'same')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Same” pads with zeros. You need to pad your input with at least `K-1` zeros (if your kernel has length `K`), then do the FFT convolution, and finally crop the result to the expected size.

`fft(x, N)` pads with zeros on the right when `N > length(x)`. So you will need to crop from the right. But because of the way that `fft(k, N)` works, the origin of the kernel is on the first sample, rather than the middle as assumed by “same”. So the result is shifted. You will thus need to remove some samples from the left side as well, probably `(K-1)/2` samples assuming `K` is odd.

Comment: You mention that I need to add pads to the right. That means that there are a difference between 2D case and 1D case where in 2D case, I need to cut the kernel in 4 pieces and place them into the corner of the augmented kernel.

Comment: @euraad No, there is no difference. Where I said the result is shifted is because the kernel is shifted, with the origin on the first sample. This is equivalent to the 2D case where the kernel is placed in the top-left corner of the image instead. A shifted kernel leads to a shifted output. Because we must crop the output anyway, we can crop taking the shift into account.